# equivalent of within(), attach() etc. for working within an environment?

Tags: r, closures

I want to add an environment to a search path and modify the values of variables within that environment, in a limited chunk of code, without having to specify the name of the environment every time I refer to a variable: for example, given the environment

```
ee <- list2env(list(x=1,y=2))
```

Now I would like to do stuff like

```
ee$x <- ee$x+1
ee$y <- ee$y*2
ee$z <- 6
```

but without appending `ee$` to everything (or using `assign("x", ee$x+1, ee)` ... etc.): something like

```
in_environment(ee, {
    x <- x+1
    y <- y+2
    z <- 6
})
```

Most of the solutions I can think of are explicitly designed **not** to modify the environment, e.g.

- `?attach:` "The database is not actually attached.  Rather, a new environment
  is created on the search path ..."
- `within()`: takes *lists or data frames* (not environments) "... and makes the corresponding modifications to a copy of ‘data’"
- There are two problems with `<<-`: (1) using it will cause NOTEs in CRAN checks (I think? can't find direct evidence of this, but e.g. [see here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/1861) — maybe this only happens because of the appearance of assigning to a locally undefined symbol? I guess I could put this in a package and test it with `--as-cran` to confirm ...); (2) it will try to assign in the parent environment, which in a package context [which this is] will be locked ...

I suppose I could use a closure as described in section 10.7 of the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) by doing

```
clfun <- function() {
   x <- 1
   y <- 2
   function(...) {
      x <<- x + 1   
      y <<- y * 2
   }
}
myfun <- clfun()
```

This seems convoluted (but I guess not too bad?) but:

- will still incur problem #1 (CRAN check?).
- I think (??) it won't work with variables that don't already exist in the environment (would need an explicit `assign()` for that ...)
- doesn't allow a choice of which environment to operate in - it's necessarily going to work in the enclosing environment, not with arbitrary environment `ee`

Am I missing something obvious and idiomatic?

Comment: What about `with()`? [Here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/with) it says `with` can take an environment as its argument? I don't really know what you're doing, though, so I'm sorry if this is not even close to what you're looking for.

Comment: You may be right!

Comment: @Nuclear03020704, if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `with()`? From [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/with),

> `with(data, expr)`
>
> `data` is the data to use for constructing an environment. For the default with method this may be an environment, a list, a data frame, or an integer.
>
> `expr` is the expression to evaluate.
>
> `with` is a generic function that evaluates `expr` in a local environment constructed from data. The environment has the caller's environment as its parent. This is useful for simplifying calls to modeling functions. (Note: if `data` is already an environment then this is used with its existing parent.)
>
> Note that assignments within `expr` take place in the constructed environment and not in the user's workspace.
>
> `with()` returns value of the evaluated `expr`.

---

```
ee <- list2env(list(x=1,y=2))
with(ee, {
    x <- x+1
    y <- y+2
    z <- 6
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Nuclear03020704 ! I think `with()` was what I wanted all along; I was incorrectly assuming that it would also create a local copy of the environment, but it only does this if the `data` argument is **not already an environment**.

```
ee <- list2env(list(x=1,y=2))
with(ee, {
    x <- x+1
    y <- y+2
    z <- 6
})
```

does exactly that I want.

---

Just had another idea, which also seems to have some drawbacks: using a big `eval` clause. Rather than make my question a long laundry list of unsatisfactory solutions, I'll add it here.

```
myfun <- function() {
    eval(quote( {
        x <- x+1
        y <- y*2
        z <- 3
    }), envir=ee)
}
```

This does seem to work, but also seems very weird/mysterious! I hate to think about explaining it to someone who's being using R for less than 10 years ... I suppose I could write an `in_environment()` based on this, but I'd have to be very careful to capture the expression properly without evaluating it ...

Comment: It's not that tricky to capture the environment, is it? For example i think `in_environment <- function(ee, code) {eval(substitute(code), envir=ee, enclos=parent.frame())}` should do what you want (unless i'm missing something)

Comment: But I don't think that would pass CRAN checks. It seems those checks don't like it when package code use non-standard evaluation. Guess it's supposed to be a user-only convenience. Symbols not in formulas that aren't explicit defined usually cause problems. But I'd be curious if anyone knows of counter-examples.

Comment: `globalVariables()` is supposed to take care of this (although Martin Maechler doesn't like it and prefers `x <- y <- NULL` (which doesn't work in this case) ... not sure why ...